# change image with for loop statement in Xamarin

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, xamarin

I have 13 images shown in page ,one of them is fixed and others changed depend on some data ,i made 12 if statement and it works ,but is there way to create one if statement with for loop like thus :

```
for (int i = 2; i >= 13; i++)
            {
                if (m_id >= i)
                {
                    
                    "image" + i.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("months" + i + ".png");
                }
                else
                {
                    "image" + i.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("months"+i+"closed.png");
                }
            }
```

Comment: i did it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all Images in an **Array** like

```
List<Image> Images = new List<Image>() {image2,image3,...,image13 };
```

And set the **ImageSource** like

```
for(int i=2;i<=13;i++)
{
   Image image = Images[i - 2];
   
   if (m_id >= i)   
    {
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("months" + i + ".png");
    }

    else
    {
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("months"+i+"closed.png");
    }

}
```

Comment: my images is ImageButton is this way compatible with it ?

Comment: Yes, you can put anything in the List .